# MySql - having issues with double left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am having issues with getting this double left join to get the listingspecificsListPrice, but that info exists in the table, cant figure out why it would not include it. This is my sql.

```
SELECT mls_subject_property.*, mls_images.imagePath, mls_forms_listing_specifics.listingspecificsListPrice  
FROM mls_subject_property 
LEFT JOIN mls_images ON mls_subject_property.mls_listingID = mls_images.mls_listingID 
LEFT JOIN mls_forms_listing_specifics ON mls_forms_listing_specifics.mls_listingID = mls_subject_property.mls_listingID AND mls_images.imgOrder = 0 
WHERE userID = 413 
GROUP BY mls_subject_property.mls_listingID
```

The result comes out like this..
[image]

All of the other fields come back, but it doesnt seem to want to bring back those two items.
This is a picture of the other table, to show that the data does in fact exist.
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation functions?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

The `mls_images.imgOrder = 0` condition should be in the join with `mls_images`, not `mls_forms_listing_specifics`.

Don't use `GROUP BY` if you're not using any aggregation functions. Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to prevent duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT mls_subject_property.*, mls_images.imagePath, mls_forms_listing_specifics.listingspecificsListPrice  
FROM mls_subject_property 
LEFT JOIN mls_images ON mls_subject_property.mls_listingID = mls_images.mls_listingID AND mls_images.imgOrder = 0
LEFT JOIN mls_forms_listing_specifics ON mls_forms_listing_specifics.mls_listingID = mls_subject_property.mls_listingID 
WHERE userID = 413
```

Comment: hmm, I have it setup like this in my code, but that does not seem to make a difference.
$sql = " SELECT msp.*, mls_images.imagePath, mls_forms_listing_specifics.listingspecificsListPrice "; 
  $sql .= " FROM mls_subject_property as msp ";
  $sql .= " LEFT JOIN mls_images ON msp.mls_listingID = mls_images.mls_listingID "; 
  $sql .= " LEFT JOIN mls_forms_listing_specifics ON msp.mls_listingID = mls_forms_listing_specifics.mls_listingID ";
  $sql .= " AND mls_images.imgOrder = 0 ";
  $sql .= " WHERE userID = ".$userID.  " ";
  $sql .= " GROUP BY msp.mls_listingID ";

Comment: Please create a [sqlfiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com) with sample data.

Comment: Try getting rid of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: ok I figured out why it is not displaying it, but dont know how to solve the issue. Because the user has not uploaded any images yet, it is not bringing back the image data naturally, but it is also not bringing back the mls_forms_listing_specifics.listingspecificsListPrice   which is strange no? So after I uploaded an image, it is bringing back the image, and the  mls_forms_listing_specifics.listingspecificsListPrice. I would like it to bring back the price even if an image is not uploaded yet

Comment: Yes, that's strange. That would happen if you used `mls_images.mls_listingId` in the second `LEFT JOIN`.